# Maximize $\log\det(I+X\Sigma)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

\begin{array}{ll}\max\limits_{{X:\,\mathrm{tr}(X)\leq a\\}} \log\det(I+X\Sigma),\end{array}

where $\Sigma=\mathrm{diag}\{\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n\}$, $\sigma_i\geq0$ and $a>0$ are given. And $X\geq 0$.

Here I am trying to maximize a concave function with a convex constraints.
Any hints on how the problem can be solved?

Comment: I've changed the title so that it fits better into the list of new questions.  Could you provide a bit of context for this question?  For instance: how did you encounter the problem?  Have you tried anything yourself?  Are there any methods that you expect will/won't work here?

Comment: I suspect that the maximizer will be another diagonal matrix in this case.  I would try plugging in
$$
X = \pmatrix{x_1 \\ & \ddots \\ && x_n}
$$
(where the blank entries are zero) and maximize using a method like Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, First I tried $n=2$ case for $\Sigma=I$, I can solve this problem using AM-GM, I believe it can be generalized to higher dimensions. When $\Sigma\neq I$, then we want to maximize $x_1\sigma_1+x_2\sigma_2+x_1x_2\sigma_1\sigma_2$ for $x_1+x_2\leq a$, from here I don't know how to solve.

Comment: This seems to be analogous to finding the capacity of a Gaussian channel. I vote writing out the KKT conditions (cf. davidrosenberg.github.io/ml2015/docs/convex-optimization.pdf) and trying to solve. For a similar example, see example 5.2 in web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf. Maybe look at chapter 9 in http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~cgong821/Wiley.Interscience.Elements.of.Information.Theory.Jul.2006.eBook-DDU.pdf.

Comment: Also, a fun fact that is probably helpful is Hadamard's Inequality, which essentially  tells you that you can assume a diagonal X, as @Omnomnomnom mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the constrained matrix variable $X$ in terms of an unconstrained matrix $Y$ as follows 
$$X = \frac{\alpha Y}{{\rm Tr}(Y)} \implies {\rm Tr}(X) = \alpha$$
The following variables will also be useful
$$B = I+X\Sigma,\quad W^T=\Sigma B^{-1},\quad \tau={\rm Tr}(Y) = I:Y$$
Find the gradient of the function wrt $Y$
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \log\det(B) \\
d\phi
 &= B^{-T}:dB \\
 &= B^{-T}:dX\,\Sigma \\
 &= W:dX \\
 &= W:\Big({\alpha\tau^{-1}\,dY-\alpha\tau^{-2}Y(I:dY)}\Big) \\
 &= \Big(\alpha\tau^{-1}W-(W:Y)\alpha\tau^{-2}I\Big):dY \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial Y} &= \alpha\tau^{-1}W-(W:Y)\alpha\tau^{-2}I \\
}$$
Set the gradient to zero and solve, per usual for an *unconstrained* problem.
$$\eqalign{
W &= (W:Y)\tau^{-1}I \;=\; \lambda I \\
\lambda I &= W = W^T = \Sigma B^{-1} = \Sigma(I+X\Sigma)^{-1} \\
\Sigma &= \lambda(I+X\Sigma) \\
X &= (\Sigma - \lambda I)(\lambda\Sigma)^{+} \;=\; \lambda^{-1}\Sigma\Sigma^{+}-\Sigma^{+} \\
}$$ where $\Sigma^+$ is the pseudoinverse of $\Sigma$.

All that remains is to find the value of $\lambda$, which can be calculated by enforcing the original trace constraint.
$$\eqalign{
\alpha
 &= {\rm Tr}(X) \\
 &= \lambda^{-1}{\rm Tr}(\Sigma\Sigma^{+}) - {\rm Tr}(\Sigma^{+}) \\
 &= \lambda^{-1}{\rm rank}(\Sigma) - {\rm Tr}(\Sigma^{+})  \\
\lambda &= \frac{{\rm rank}(\Sigma)}{\alpha+{\rm Tr}(\Sigma^{+})}
}$$
In the above derivation, the symmetry of $\Sigma$ was utilized, but the fact that it is diagonal was not needed. However, since $(\Sigma,\Sigma^+)$ are diagonal, $X$ is as well.

Finally, enforce non-negativity by taking
$$X = (\lambda\Sigma)^{+}\max(0, \,\Sigma - \lambda I)$$

**NB:** In several steps, a colon is used to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$